# multiple search using awk - pattern + arithmetic condition

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to use awk command to perform multiple search to fetch records from a log file WHERE it matches following 2 conditions :

1. pattern - EXEC_TIME
2. last column i.e. having EXEC_TIME > 5000 ms.

I tried and used below command but its not giving me correct output, not sure if can be use same way!

I am just learning awk so any help will be appreciated.

```
awk -F ':' '/EXEC_TIME/&&$15>="5000"{print $2,$15}' TransactionInfoLogs.log

MP170420.0548.T00003[SERV] 9065 ms
OC170420.0655.T00001[SERV] 708 ms
```

Below is sample log file:

```
[TXN_ID]:MP170420.0548.T00003[SERV][SERV]:BLKSRVREQ[MSISDN]:8028359017[SV_CHRG_ID]:37152[RESP_CODE]:200[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:23 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:23 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:9065 ms
[TXNID]:XX170420.1244.C01465[TYPE]:SERVICE_CHARGE_PAYER_PAYEE[AMT]:0[PR_MSISDN]:8028359017[PR_MFS]:101[PR_W_TYPE]:12[PR_PREBAL]:0[PR_BAL]:0[PY_MSISDN]:IND03[PY_MFS]:101[PY_W_TYPE]:null[PY_PRE
BAL]:2782239[PY_BAL]:2782239
[2017-04-20 12:44:29,552][http-bio-172.24.87.5-7890-exec-7365]- 
[TXN_ID]:XX170420.1244.C01467[SERV]:null[MSISDN]:8080967233[RESP_CODE]:00066[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:29 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:29 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:9 ms
[2017-04-20 12:44:36,634][http-bio-172.24.87.5-7890-exec-7364]- 
[TXN_ID]:OC170420.0655.T00001[SERV]:null[MSISDN]:7016532415[RESP_CODE]:00066[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:36 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:36 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:708 ms
[2017-04-20 12:44:45,820][http-bio-172.24.87.5-7890-exec-7359]- 
[TXN_ID]:XX170420.1244.C01471[SERV]:null[MSISDN]:8026136275[RESP_CODE]:00066[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:45 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:45 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:39 ms
[2017-04-20 12:44:46,010][http-bio-172.24.87.5-7890-exec-7366]- 
[TXN_ID]:XX170420.1244.C01473[SERV]:BLKSRVREQ[MSISDN]:8127459541[SV_CHRG_ID]:37152[RESP_CODE]:200[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:45 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:46 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:221 ms
[TXNID]:XX170420.1244.C01473[TYPE]:SERVICE_CHARGE_PAYER_PAYEE[AMT]:0[PR_MSISDN]:8127459541[PR_MFS]:101[PR_W_TYPE]:12[PR_PREBAL]:0[PR_BAL]:0[PY_MSISDN]:IND03[PY_MFS]:101[PY_W_TYPE]:null[PY_PRE
BAL]:2853870[PY_BAL]:2853870
[2017-04-20 12:44:49,989][http-bio-172.24.87.5-7890-exec-7371]- 
[TXN_ID]:XX170420.1244.C01475[SERV]:BLKSRVREQ[MSISDN]:8089138902[SV_CHRG_ID]:37152[RESP_CODE]:200[START]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:49 WAT 2017 [END]:Thu Apr 20 12:44:49 WAT 2017[EXEC_TIME]:57 ms
[TXNID]:XX170420.1244.C01475[TYPE]:SERVICE_CHARGE_PAYER_PAYEE[AMT]:0[PR_MSISDN]:8089138902[PR_MFS]:101[PR_W_TYPE]:12[PR_PREBAL]:0[PR_BAL]:0[PY_MSISDN]:IND03[PY_MFS]:101[PY_W_TYPE]:null[PY_PRE
BAL]:3071459[PY_BAL]:3071459
```

Comment: rather than count the number of fields, you can use `print $2, $NF` to print the what you need. `NF`=Number_of_Fields so, with the leading `$` char, using `$NF` will print the value of the last field on the line. You can also do "math" on the number returned by `NF` and for example, print 3rd to last field, i.e `$(NF-3)`. Good luck.

Comment: Don't just say `not giving me correct output` and leave it at that. **Show** us the correct/expected output and explain in what way the output you're getting is `not correct`.

Comment: May interest you doing with **Perl** : `perl -F':' -ne '/(?<=\[EXEC_TIME\]:)\d+/ &&  $& > 5000 && print "$F[1] and $&" ' file`

Comment: @shellter : thanks , its a helpful tip.

Comment: @EdMorton: Noted, please pardon me as it was my first post.

Comment: @k-five : thanks , but seems its giving only field i.e. last field `perl -F':' -ne '/(?<=\[EXEC_TIME\]:)\d+/ && $& > 3000 && print "$F[1] and $&" ' TransactionInfoLogs.log
 and 3107 and 3174 and 3055 and 3097 and 3037 and 3486 and 9749 and 3147 and 3157 and 3186`

Comment: which field do you want?

Comment: @k-five: 2nd and last i.e. `MP170420.0548.T00003 9065 ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have name->value mappings in an input file it's a good idea to first create an array of that mapping (`n2v[]` below) and then you can just reference each field by it's name rather than it's position, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete n2v
    while ( match($0,/\[[^]]+]:/) ) {
        if ( name != "" ) {
            value = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
            sub(/\[.*/,"",value)
            n2v[name] = value
        }
        name = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-3)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    value = $0
    n2v[name] = value

    for (name in n2v) {
        value = n2v[name]
        print name, "->", value
    }
}

$ head -1 file | awk -f tst.awk
EXEC_TIME -> 9065 ms
START -> Thu Apr 20 12:44:23 WAT 2017
RESP_CODE -> 200
SV_CHRG_ID -> 37152
TXN_ID -> MP170420.0548.T00003
END -> Thu Apr 20 12:44:23 WAT 2017
MSISDN -> 8028359017
SERV -> BLKSRVREQ
```

You can then tweak the above to do whatever you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    delete n2v
    while ( match($0,/\[[^]]+]:/) ) {
        if ( name != "" ) {
            value = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
            sub(/\[.*/,"",value)
            n2v[name] = value
        }
        name = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-3)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    value = $0
    n2v[name] = value
}

n2v["EXEC_TIME"]+0 > 5000 { print n2v["TXN_ID"], n2v["EXEC_TIME"] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
MP170420.0548.T00003 9065 ms
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. It works like charm 

`[2335145@txn01 txn_logs]$ awk -f /tmp/tst.awk TransactionInfoLogs.log 
MP170424.0007.A45538 9749 ms
XX170424.0050.A39964 9871 ms`